# Problem in showing post-hoc Tukey analysis in a table

Tags: r

I think this is a stupid question, but I am kind of stuck. I want to put my posthoc Tukey analysis in a table, however, I am not able to do that. The steps I followed are:
First, I converted the posthoc Tukey result into a data frame then I used the gt package to make a table.

The problem is I am not able to show my groups in the table, in this case the name of the islands

This is the code I am using

```
Tuk_anova1 <- TukeyHSD(AnovaModel.1)
Tuk_anova1 <- TukeyHSD(AnovaModel.1)
Tuk_anova1
TK <-as.data.frame(Tuk_anova1$Island)
gt_tbl <- gt(TK)
gt_tbl
```

[The table I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANLwP.png)
[TukeyHSD result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox0SV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `rownames_to_stub=TRUE` argument. Here is an example:

```
library(gt)
data(iris)
iris.aov <- aov(Sepal.Width~Species, iris)
iris.hsd <- TukeyHSD(iris.aov)
iris.df <- as.data.frame(iris.hsd$Species)
gt_tbl <- gt(iris.df, rownames_to_stub=TRUE)
gt_tbl
```

[image: Table]